# Minikube ssh failing (ssh: handshake failed)

Tags: ssh, minikube

Friends, I need to access the minikube environment for debugging - need to check the content of my volumes - and since yesterday I can't. When I run "minikube ssh" I get the following error:

**ssh: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain.**

Everything else seems to be working just fine. Any idea how to fix this? I don't even know how to start.

I am using minikube version v1.15.0, MacOs Catalina 10.15.07 and Virtualbox 6.1.16

Comment: Can you share more info about your environment? Minikube version, driver used (virtualbox/ hyper-v etc), OS used.

Comment: minikube version: v1.15.0 - MacOs Catalina 10.15.07 - Virtualbox 6.1.16

Answer (score 2):

I still have no idea what the problem was but since I restarted my computer, it is working again. The interesting thing is that I started my computer yesterday as well and when I ran it  I was still having this problem. I will keep paying attention to it.